# After HelloWorld iPhone app, how to move on to app for handling WAV files

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, wav

I have just started to work with the iPhone SDk(have never worked with MAC either). I finished implementing a helloworld app on iPhone.
I'm supposed to build an app on the iPhone for handling WAV files. How do I start? Which frameworks should I look at? Please advice.

Regards,
Namratha

Comment: First is to get a good clear recording of you saying "hello world".

Comment: OK. I want to open an existing WAV file. I have the C code. How do I translate it into an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the best way would be start from apples documentations, search with your requirements.There will be methods that you may be instrested in.(Praise their naming conventions).Then if its not clear to you what is being said, do a google search on that part.This is the approach i followed at the start.
Eg:AudioToolBox framework